# Cannot see all disks on Solaris 10 using on a Dell Perc5i Dual Channel Raid Controller

Tags: raid, solaris, dell-poweredge, dell-perc

I have a Dell PowerEdge 2950 running Solaris 10 with 8 drives.  I want to swap some of the drives out for new ones. My issue as of right now is that I only see half of them and there does not appear to be any sign of the other 4.

**server info -**

```
# cat /etc/release
                    Solaris 10 5/09 s10x_u7wos_08 X86
       Copyright 2009 Sun Microsystems, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.
                    Use is subject to license terms.
                         Assembled 30 March 2009
```

**cfgadm output -**

```
# cfgadm -al
Ap_Id                          Type         Receptacle   Occupant     Condition
c0                             scsi-bus     connected    configured   unknown
c0::dsk/c0t0d0                 disk         connected    configured   unknown
c0::dsk/c0t1d0                 disk         connected    configured   unknown
c0::dsk/c0t2d0                 disk         connected    configured   unknown
c0::dsk/c0t3d0                 disk         connected    configured   unknown
usb0/1                         unknown      empty        unconfigured ok
usb0/2                         unknown      empty        unconfigured ok
usb1/1                         unknown      empty        unconfigured ok
usb1/2                         unknown      empty        unconfigured ok
usb2/1                         unknown      empty        unconfigured ok
usb2/2                         unknown      empty        unconfigured ok
usb3/1                         unknown      empty        unconfigured ok
usb3/2                         unknown      empty        unconfigured ok
usb4/1                         unknown      empty        unconfigured ok
usb4/2                         unknown      empty        unconfigured ok
usb4/3                         unknown      empty        unconfigured ok
usb4/4                         unknown      empty        unconfigured ok
usb4/5                         usb-hub      connected    configured   ok
usb4/5.1                       unknown      empty        unconfigured ok
usb4/5.2                       unknown      empty        unconfigured ok
usb4/5.3                       unknown      empty        unconfigured ok
usb4/5.4                       unknown      empty        unconfigured ok
usb4/6                         unknown      empty        unconfigured ok
usb4/7                         unknown      empty        unconfigured ok
usb4/8                         unknown      empty        unconfigured ok
```

**raidctl** outputs absolutely nothing

**format output -**

```
AVAILABLE DISK SELECTIONS:
       0. c0t0d0 <DEFAULT cyl 8841 alt 2 hd 255 sec 63>
          /pci@0,0/pci8086,25e3@3/pci8086,370@0/pci1028,1f03@e/sd@0,0
       1. c0t1d0 <DELL-PERC 5/i-1.03-67.75GB>
          /pci@0,0/pci8086,25e3@3/pci8086,370@0/pci1028,1f03@e/sd@1,0
       2. c0t2d0 <DELL-PERC 5/i-1.03-67.75GB>
          /pci@0,0/pci8086,25e3@3/pci8086,370@0/pci1028,1f03@e/sd@2,0
       3. c0t3d0 <DELL-PERC 5/i-1.03-67.75GB>
          /pci@0,0/pci8086,25e3@3/pci8086,370@0/pci1028,1f03@e/sd@3,0
Specify disk (enter its number): ^C
```

Comment: Normally you would use the MegaCLI command-line configuration utility to manage this model of RAID controller as the Solaris 10 HCL says to use the mega_sas driver for it.

Comment: Please move the output of your commands into your question rather than hosting images externally, as it's very relevant to your problem.

Comment: @Brian MegaCLI doesn't appear to be installed. Would it have to be there already or would it be something I can install now to manage the RAID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to start with managing the RAID controller with MegaCLI or MegaRAID Storage Manager (as Brian mentioned), which requires the proper driver be in place. Oracle's hardware comparability list points you in the direction of the proper driver to use...

- [Oracle's HCL Page for the PERC5i](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/hcl/1442477.html)

...but the link is no good, likely because of how old the hardware is. However, a quick search on the LSI site still pulls the driver and software needed:

- [LSI Driver Download](http://www.lsi.com/downloads/Public/RAID%20Controllers/RAID%20Controllers%20Common%20Files/6.605.01.00-MR_Solaris_Driver.tgz)
- [MegaCLI](http://www.lsi.com/downloads/Public/RAID%20Controllers/RAID%20Controllers%20Common%20Files/8.07.14_MegaCLI.zip)
- [MegaRAID Storage Manager (Solaris 10 x86)](http://www.lsi.com/downloads/Public/RAID%20Controllers/RAID%20Controllers%20Common%20Files/14.08.01.02_Solaris10_MSM.tar.gz)

The driver install may just turn out to solve the issue... if not, you'll have to dig for info with MegaCLI to troubleshoot. And not to just leave you with "RTFM", but you *will* need to read up a little on the MegaCLI guide to find how to get relevant data on the issue. You may just start with some web searches (e.g. "MegaCLI show all disks") if the guide is a bit overwhelming.

Update via comment w/ any progress/results?

Comment: ok I'm not gonna lie, im not too familiar with solaris.  I unpacked the tarball and cd to /intel/Solaris 10 and am not sure how to actually install it from this point.  If I unpack the components.tgz I get mr_sas.img, mr_sas.iso, and mr_sas.tar.Z.  I've tried doing a pkgadd on each and even unpacked mr_sas.tar.Z. I'm stumped at this point.

Comment: I'm not much of a Solaris expert either - I know enough w/ Linux to stumble through most things w/ some web searching though.
It looks like you'd need to mount the ISO file buried a couple TGZs deep:
6.605.01.00-MR_Solaris_Driver.tgz/intel/Solaris10/components.tgz/./mr_sas.iso
Then use the install.sh script on the ISO at:
/DU/sol_210/i86pc/Tools/

Comment: Thank you was able to get everything installed and played with MegaCLI a bit and was able to pull this info http://pastebin.com/kDuV0arg for the drives via MegaCli -PDList -aALL.  It appears to show them all but I'd like more info like if they are hot swappable.

Comment: This might be helpful for someone in the future as well http://tools.rapidsoft.de/perc/perc-cheat-sheet.html

Comment: It's tough to find documentation on the PERC5/i - Dell has next to nothing, though there's a little on the MIT web site. I believe that the controller CAN support hot swap, but it may depend on firmware version whether it actually works. I'd recommend playing it safe though and shutting down.